# Python Selenium - Div changing when hovering and focusing - Unable to locate element

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to fill out a form, but no matter what I try, I get the error message Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

It looks like the div class is changing when the form field "Brugernavn" is hovered as well as when it is focused.

I have tried a number of different setups with both css selector, ids and xpaths and with hovering first before trying to fill out the form, but I can't make it work.

The form is found on the right of the website:
https://gls-group.eu/DK/da/home

Comment: Thanks @JeffC - it worked! I'll make sure to be more specific and share my research, code attempts and results in future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS selector

```
input[placeholder='Brugernavn']
```